# no applicable method for 'inner_join' applied to an object of class "character"?

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I’m trying to unite two different columns: `Type.1` and `Type.2`. Both have the same  type (character) but when I try an `inner_join()` I get the following message:

```r
library(dplyr)

type_united <- inner_join(data1$Type.1,data1$Type.2)
# no applicable method for 'inner_join' applied to an object of class "character"
```

I get the same mistake while trying a `left_join()` (sometimes `Type.2` has a null value, so I figured it could solve the problem).

What could I do to unify these two columns into a single one?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please have a look how to make a [great MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Judging from your code, it seems that you are trying to input the content of the columns directly into `inner_join` and also don't use 2 different data.frames. Joinas are performed on 2 data sets, have a look at the dplyr vignette: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/two-table.html

Comment: To unite your type columns you could use e.g. `paste(data1$Type.1, data1$Type.2, sep = ".")` which will use a `"."` as the separator but feel free to choose your own.

Comment: Stefan, that is a great alternative solution, but unfortunately the plotting will have too many variables. I wanted to keep it a bit more concise, so keeping only the original character strings would be optimal (just single types, instead of them together). I wanted to count the total quantity of pokemon of each type, regardless of it being mixed or secondary.

Comment: Would something like `data1 %>% pivot_longer(cols =c('Type1', 'Type2')) %>% count(value)` be useful for your counting objective?

Comment: The notion of join/merge is a table-centric (in R, `data.frame`-centric) operation, c.f., https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/5706437/3358272. It is not something one does on strings. With strings, there is the notion of concatenating/combining, or in R parlance, `paste`ing them. I don't know which you want, and so long as this question is not reproducible, it's going to be difficult to give you much help.